# Installing MathJax and showing formulae

Tags: jquery, html

I try to use mathjax:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Math</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/math/css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
            MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
        <!--
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/math/js/math/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
        -->
    </head>
    <body>
        When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
        $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
    </body>
</html>
```

it works if i load the mathjax from

```
http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```

, but it dowsn't work in my downloaded mathjax last version

```
http://localhost/math/js/math/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML ?
```

How to config, that it show formulae instead of red "[Math Processing Error]"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your local version isn't installed properly.  Did you install all the files, including the image fonts?  Are the fonts being served with the proper MIME types?  Are the file permissions correct on all the files and directories so the server can read them properly?

Try checking the web server log to see if here are any useful error messages about files being requested but not served.  Also, you could type `javascript:alert(MathJax.Message.Log())` in the URL area of your browser and see if there are any messages about files or fonts failing to be loaded.  (In Firefox, you may need to use the Javascript console rather than the URL area, and then just type `MathJax.Message.Log()` instead).

Did you load the `MathJax/test/index.html` file to see if everything is working there?

It is almost surely an installation issue.  Good luck.